# [PCL]: When acronyms attack!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

The [printer-control-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printer-control-language) tag has, ah, a *few* questions having something to do with printing. Most of them seem to involve computer vision or .NET assemblies instead, though. That's because questions involving the [point-cloud-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point-cloud-library), or [portable-class-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portable-class-library), get tagged [pcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcl) and then synonymized to everyone's favorite driver headache.

Suggest removing the synonym, and probably burninating [pcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcl) itself.

Comment: Sounds good to me! We definitely have SAOD (Severe Acronym Overload Disorder) around here (https://youtu.be/KbSPPFYxx3o?t=5m23s), and that overlap can certainly cause confustion.

Comment: Burninate the acronyms from orbit.

Comment: Yep. From orbit. It's the only way TBS. ... uh, I mean 'to be sure'.

Comment: Disagree. If I had some printer-control-language question, I'm not going to tag it with the right thing unless `pcl` or `pcl5` or _something_ points to it.

Comment: The title needs more pun, like _"In a [pcl]"_ (pickle). The Point Cloud Library _is_ computer-vision-related, so that's not just appearances.

Comment: Unfortunately HP started it with their insistence on calling it PCL from the very beginning. The meaning of the acronym was buried to the point of oblivion.

Comment: All TLAs should be YOLO. The first one to use it gets it for all time.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist -  PCL, Please Clarify Language?

Comment: I don't even see the point in having Stack Overflow accepting any acronyms in the first place. The collision risk is too high... and it can't think of any benefit because we have auto-completion right ? but maybe I'm wrong ?...

Comment: @FabienBondi how do you programmatically detect if a string is an acronym or a word without having false positives?

Comment: @TinyGiant Ask wikipedia ? google ? compute an acronym probability and if it's greater than a threshold ... ok :) you're right...I bow before you

Comment: Totally agree with this request. I just cleaned up a few questions again, that use [printer-control-language] when they should really be using [point-cloud-library] instead. I would estimate that about 3 out of 4 questions that are tagges [pcl] make that mistake...

Comment: Tag got recreated today (mar 2019), probably not used often enough to blacklist but still noting it.

Answer (score 22):

I'd suggest dropping `pcl` but keeping (or creating - I don't know if they already exist) `pcl5` and `pcl6`. People looking for help with printing are more likely to recognise those than `printer-control-language`, and having two different tags will help people narrow down their problem. (Despite the similar names, PCL5 and PCL6 are completely different, unrelated languages; anything related to either one is unlikely to be relevant to the other.)

Comment: They are related by marketing!