Remove "pcl" tag as it is synonym for "point-cloud-library" tag and therefore redundant
pcl tag has no user guidance nor wiki and all questions with that tag refer to point-cloud-library anyway. Should pcl be made a synonym of point-cloud-library? Alternatively, can pcl be replaced by point-cloud-library?

Seems making is a synonym would be the better™ option to me; if all the (150+) questions are about [[tag:point-cloud-library]], and it's still getting consistent use, then removal of it could just result in it coming back.

@ThomA pardon my ignorance, but can I make a tag synonym and if yes, then how do I do that?

What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?

PCL is sometimes used as a synonym for 'perf' (a Linux profiling tool). 'perf' tag wiki.

The first thing coming to my mind when I read PCL is Printer Command Language

To me it means Pacific Coach Lines or Pacific Contracting Ltd.. Three Letter acronyms suck.

@user4581301 good thing we're not meta.sports.stackexchange.com. I'd very much expect to find answers relating to printer command language here.

the unguidanced TLA-tag [[tag:pcl]] is now empty. enjoy.

related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307166/pcl-when-acronyms-attack

Nice find, @Jonas. Funny to note that the same dude who deleted the synonym there wrote an answer here suggesting to create the synonym. (My brain prolly reset after resigning)

I support what Bhargav Rao said for the most part. The questions tagged pcl which use it to mean point-cloud-library can be re-tagged.
However, the rest I propose be mass-retagged to point-cloud-library and thus the pcl tag be burned.
It is already used for different things, so in the future more people would still use it for Printer Control Language or Portable Class Library or maybe even other technologies that are not out yet. It is better to eliminate the confusion when there clearly is some. Synonyms work when there is no inherent confusion, otherwise, they just turn into a future maintenance burden.

A better link to illustrate the maintenance burden of synonyms might be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307166/pcl-when-acronyms-attack. :-) More substantively, I somewhat disagree. For a tag that is on-face ambiguous (such as one that is a three-letter acronym), if there is no synonym, the tag is likely to be re-created. This is historically borne out across multiple cases. However, if there is a synonym, then at least there's a chance that someone will notice that the obviously wrong tag is used (because the attempt to use the TLA tag is auto-replaced with the full, wrong one).

@CodyGray "if there is a synonym, then at least there's a chance that someone will notice that the obviously wrong tag is used (because the attempt to use the TLA tag is auto-replaced with the full, wrong one)" well, yarn didn't get that revelation. I had to waste a lot of time cleaning up before I requested the synonym retraction. I don't want more of this. If a tag is ambiguous and made a synonym people will use it incorrectly - the synonym doesn't fix it. While if the tag is re-created, it's not that big of a deal to go through the questions in it.

Out of the 155 questions, there are some 55 questions tagged with PCL, but do not have Point Cloud in them.
After checking a few of them, it looks like they refer to other usages of PCL as well.

There are the questions related to Printer Command/Control Language like Bill mentions in the comments. Fortunately, there is a tag printer-control-language for that. So we need to retag those.
There is also the portable-class-library for those questions related to that project.

We need to cleanup these 55 questions and later synonymize pcl to point-cloud-library.

So who is going to bell the cat?

Usually someone who knows the topic, @Abra. You can always start with a few questions when you're free, and then curate them over a few days.

So you're suggesting that I remove the pcl tag if the question already has the other, appropriate tag, e.g. if the question is about Point Cloud Library and already has point-cloud-library tag or replace the pcl tag with the appropriate tag, e.g. if the question is about Printer Control Language then replace pcl tag with printer-control-language. Is that correct?

If the question is about Point Cloud Library, then just leave it as is. When we synonymize the tags, it'll be automatically updated. When the question isn't about Point Cloud Library, then remove the [tag:pcl] tag and add whatever tag is appropriate. You'd need to go through just those 55 questions, not all the 156 questions.

"We need to cleanup these 55 questions and later synonymize pcl to point-cloud-library." given that already a third of the questions use pcl to mean something different, I think this will just exacerbate the problem in the future when somebody asks for, say, Printer Control Language and tags it [[tag:pcl]]. It seems more prudent to first re-tag the non-point cloud library questions, then mass retag the rest to [[tag:point-cloud-library]] and burn [[tag:pcl]].

@VLAZ, from what I've seen, even if we burn [pcl], it'll be recreated after a while. If there is a moderator who's following the recreated tags and killing them as and when it comes up, then it should be fine. But if we don't have anyone to play that whack a mole game, then it is just better to synonymize (and merge) it with what's the most used tag.

@BhargavRao and from what I've seen, synonym would mean that the tag would still be misused but it'd be way harder to track down now, since it the Portable Class Library questions will now be tagged [[tag:point-cloud-library]]. At least when re-created, there would be a relatively small questions to sort through. Not every [[tag:point-cloud-library]] question in existence (as it'd be unclear for most when the cutoff point was. Moreover, old questions could have been re-tagged in the mean time). If re-created, we can can then consider blocklisting it, too.

never underestimate the amount of boredom in this world

Sometimes, @Christoph, there are advantages in doing it using the tools that exist. There are other more productive tasks that you can tackle during your periods of boredom. But thanks for your effort to help.
